# Excitation energy of a compound nucleus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I am looking to calculate the excitation energy of Polonium-210 from the masses of Helium-4 and Lead-206. Using a table of nuclides, I found that the masses are:$M_{Pb} = 205.97 \: amu, M_{He} =4.0026 = \: amu, M_{Po} = 209.98 \: amu$. The mass defect is thus:

$$\Delta M = 209.98 - 205.97 - 4.0026 = 0.0074 \: amu$$

How do I convert this mass defect value to an excitation energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 amu is 1/12 of the mass of $^{12}C$ (roughly, the mass of the proton). Converting to energy, 1 amu = 931.5 MeV. Then, the excitation energy in your xample is 6.88 MeV, which sounds reasonable.